# How to print information in .net core test projects?

Tags: logging, .net-core, mstest

What's the standard way of printing messages in a test project?

I have an Integration test project written in MSTest and each test case contains login step and the actual call etc. I need to print some messages to console to track information like which role it login as and which url it's calling.

Ideally I want the messages to show only in Debug mode.

Currently I am using `Console.WriteLine` with `#if DEBUG` directive. Is there any better way of doing it?

Comment: How come you’re needing logging in a test project?

Comment: If logging is not expected for test projects, what's the preferred ways of writing messages to console or any file in a test project? I actually only want to find a way to print messages that show in debug mode only.

Comment: The whole idea is that individual tests are that small and discreet that they are self explanatory and some form off logging is not needed. If you have too much going on then it's time to refactor and break it all down in to smaller chunks of code. What is it you are trying to output to the console and why?

Comment: I have login in [TestInitialize] and the actual request in the [TestMethod]. During the login, I printed so that I could know which environment and which role I am login as and during the actual request, I also print so that I can look at the target url of the request. These information are useful for me when a test fail so I'd like to keep them.

Comment: Are you sure that you're doing unit testing and not integration testing? Unit tests are small individual pieces of code that will run and give you results, the different test runners (VS, Resharper, NUnit, etc) will give detailed information when a test fails and why they have failed. If you're doing integration testing then you don't need a special test project and then can use whatever logging framework you wish.

Comment: Sorry I was saying it wrong. This project is an Integration test project but written in unit test framework MSTest.

Comment: If your project is purely Integration Testing then you could easily port the logic in to say for example a Console Application, then you can use logging to your hearts content...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to log anything in your unit tests. The premise being that the code in the tests speak for themselves and anyone reading them can understand what is going. If you feel the need to add logging to your tests then that is a sign that your code is too complicated and needs to be refactored.

It's a good idea to understand the principles behind [SOLID principles](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/damubetha/solid-principles-in-C-Sharp/) and refactor your code to follow these "rules". I would recommend the first principle you try to follow is the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://journal.artfuldev.com/do-you-write-solid-c-code-expanding-upon-the-single-responsibility-principle-part-1-846dc48f876a). This should help you refactor your code to make it more testable and remove the need to add logging to your tests. (NOTE: There are other examples on the internet - the links above are just examples I found with a quick search).

**EDIT**

You could create your own `logger` class to wrap your `Console.WriteLine(...)` calls e.g.

```
public static class TestLogger
{
    public static void Log(string output)
    {
#if DEBUG
        Console.WriteLine(output);
#endif
    }
}
```

and in your test code use your class

```
public class MyTests
{
    public void FirstTest()
    {
        TestLogger.Log("Just started");
    }
}
```

The fact that the logger only writes to the console in debug mode is hidden from the test code and should hopefully make it a little clearer. In the future, if you want to use `Log4Net` or another logging library you can update your `TestLogger` class and, hopefully, none of your test cases need changing :-)

Comment: Emm, it's an integration test project and the test case involve multiple steps like login, sending the request and logout etc. So I want to print to the console to track the progress of each test. Is doing logging in a test project not recommended or impossible? As long as it's possible I'd like to know.

Comment: You didn’t mention any of that in your question. Can i suggest you take look at [ask] and update your question with all the revelant information i.e why you want to do logging in your tests. It will help people provide better answers. Thanks

Comment: I've updated my answer with a possible solution to make your code cleaner